# Delete button in table view too long visible after deletion

Tags: ios, uitableview

I just compared this to other apps and they handle that nicer. I use a NSFetchedResultsController. If I delete a row in my tables, the row is deleted (animtated) and the others move up. However the delete button is visible until the rows are completely moved up. And then it disappears immediately.

In some other apps the delete button gets smaller the more the rows move up which is much nicer.

How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Try changing the row animation.

Comment: behaviour is the same, delete butotn stays visible too long

Comment: maybe they are using a custom animation i.e taking screenshots of the view at different frames and making the elements smaller before removing the element

Comment: I'm using the regular `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight]`. I'm having the exact same problem described by MichiZH whenever I delete the last row in a section but not when I delete one on the top or in the middle.